# Why does my pygame window close instantly?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am on Ubuntu and I want to use PyGame for a beginner's project. But when I run the program for the window, it only opens briefly then closes back out. How do I fix this?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,700))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PyGame program needs to at least service the event loop.  The program is opening the window, but then doing nothing, so it just closes again.

Try something like this:

```
import pygame

WINDOW_WIDTH  = 700
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 700
SKY_BLUE = (161, 255, 254)

### Open the PyGame Wdinow
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

### make a clock for later.
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

### Main Loop
done = False
while not done:
    # Handle Window Events, etc.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Handle Movement keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
        print("up")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_DOWN] ):
        print("down")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_LEFT] ):
        print("left")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] ):
        print("right")


    # Update the window
    window.fill( SKY_BLUE )

    # Flush all updates out to the window
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp frame-rate to 60 FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

pygame.quit()
```

This opens a minimal window, handles the window-close event, paints the background blue.  It will register key-presses for arrow keys, but other than that does very little.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.